# ReactJS button loses its functionality when I resize the window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

This is the **header.component.js** file. It renders the header of the component in my react app. I'm trying to make the fontAwesome Icon that contains the "faBars" property:

```
 <Row onClick={onToggleMenu}>
        <Col>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faBars}
            size="2x"
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>
```

open and close the sidebar even when the window gets resized. The problem that I'm having is that although the icon is responsive, it loses its functionality as soon as the window resizes.

This is the entire component:

```
import React  from 'react';

import clsx from 'clsx';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { setSidebarToggleMobile } from '../redux/reducers/theme.reducer';

import HeaderUserbox from '../components/header-user-box.component';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import { faBell } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

import { faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

import { Badge, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';


// import redux and reducers
import store from "../redux/store"
import { SET_SIDEBAR_TOGGLE } from "../redux/reducers/theme.reducer"

const Header = (props) => {

  const { headerShadow, headerBgTransparent } = props;


  /** Metodo que ejecuta el toggle del sideber*/
  const onToggleMenu = () => {
    const isActive = store.getState().sidebar.sidebarToggle;
    console.log("isActive: " + isActive);
  
    //Original statement:
    store.dispatch({ type: SET_SIDEBAR_TOGGLE, sidebarToggle: !isActive });
    //console.log("Store.dispatch: " , store.dispatch({ type: SET_SIDEBAR_TOGGLE, sidebarToggle: !isActive }));
  }


  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={clsx('app-header', {
          'app-header--shadow': headerShadow,
          'app-header--opacity-bg': headerBgTransparent
        })}>          

            <Row onClick={onToggleMenu}>
              <Col>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faBars}
                  size="2x"
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>

        <div className="app-header--pane"></div>
        <div className="app-header--pane">        
          <aside className="position-relative" style={{ marginLeft: '-20%' }}>
            <Badge
              color='success'
              pill
              style={{
                zIndex: 1,
                borderRadius: '8px',
                height: '12px',
                width: '5px',
                padding: '6px',
                marginBottom: '40px',
                marginRight: '-14px',
                border: '1px solid white',
                boxShadow: '2.5px 2px'
              }}
            >
              {' '}
            </Badge>
          </aside>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faBell}
            size='4x'
            style={
              {
                borderRadius: '8px',
                zIndex: -1,
                padding: '5%',
                margin: '3%',
                width: '50px',
                backgroundColor: '#d1ffd5',
                color: '#03ac13'
              }}
          />
          <HeaderUserbox />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  headerShadow: state.sidebar.headerShadow,
  headerBgTransparent: state.sidebar.headerBgTransparent,
  sidebarToggleMobile: state.sidebar.sidebarToggleMobile
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setSidebarToggleMobile: (enable) => dispatch(setSidebarToggleMobile(enable))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

Comment: did you try adding debugger on onToggleMenu function to see whether click function is stopping there or not ?

If yes than if it's breaking in that after resize for some reason as I can see you have a very long line of object keys pair without any undefined check.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, maybe show a snippet or some link to the documentation that you're using to write the snippet

Comment: before you start make sure inspect element is opened add debugger in first line of your function onToggleMenu and after you resize click on the button and see if chrome stops at your debugger.

Comment: Okay, to summarize (and before starting to write any code), I inspect the element in the console before and after resizing the window, got it, now what am I looking for in the console? How do I recognize whether chrome stops at the debugger and how do I include the debugger (I assuming it is a snippet of code) in the first line of the onToggleMenu function

Comment: Just write word debugger in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to prevent the default event sometimes it's fixe

```js
 const onToggleMenu = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault();
    const isActive = store.getState().sidebar.sidebarToggle;
    console.log("isActive: " + isActive);
  
    //Original statement:
    store.dispatch({ type: SET_SIDEBAR_TOGGLE, sidebarToggle: !isActive });
    //console.log("Store.dispatch: " , store.dispatch({ type: SET_SIDEBAR_TOGGLE, sidebarToggle: !isActive }));
  }
```

and you can invoke your function

```
 <Row onClick={(e)=>onToggleMenu(e)}>
```

Comment: I already tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: Did you see the console.log() after a click when resize ?

Comment: Yes, the sidebar should return true when opened and false  when closed. It returns the expected

Comment: am a little bit confused , so the click is done since the isActive value is toggled => so what's exactly the expected behaviour

Comment: but it doesn't actually close or open the sidebar, it just returns the value.

Comment: The expected behavior is that it should open and close the sidebar, but it just returns the value that indicates that the sidebar has been closed without acutally closing or opening it. The weird thing is that this behavior only happens as I resize the window into a smaller size. Otherwise, it works just fine.